# Is there an isometric embedding from the Euclidean plane to the sequence space with the $\ell_1$ metric?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces, euclidean-geometry, banach-spaces, isometry

I am considering two metric spaces:

The Euclidean plane $\mathbb R^2$, equipped with the Euclidean distance metric $d((x, y), (x^\prime, y^\prime)) = \sqrt{(x - x^\prime)^2 + (y - y^\prime)^2}$, and

The sequence space $\ell_1$ with the $\ell_1$ metric $d((x_1, x_2, \dots), (x_1^\prime, x_2^\prime, \dots)) = \sum_i |x_i - x_i^\prime|$.

My question is whether there exists an isometric embedding from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\ell_1$.

**My attempt**
To investigate this, I considered a simple function

$$i: (x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mapsto (x, y, 0, 0, \dots ) \in \ell_1$$

However, it is clear that this mapping does not preserve distances, and therefore, it is not an isometric embedding. I'm looking for alternative ways to approach this problem.

If an isometric embedding is not possible, I would like to know whether an "almost isometric" embedding (an embedding that preserves distances up to a small error) might exist between these two spaces. Any insights or references related to this question would be appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#Normed_vector_spaces_satisfying_the_parallelogram_law

Comment: You might find [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvoretzky%27s_theorem) of interest.

Comment: Dvoretzky's theorem cannot be applied directly to my issue, but it presents a useful idea. Thank you.